# How does express serve index.html for React App and how do I modify it?

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm an express noob here and building a React App with server using `express` and client using `create-react-app`.

**What I want to do**

I want to update the `title` and `meta` tag in the index.html.
So `browser requests url` -> `Server gets request and adds the title and tag to the index.html` -> `return it to the browser.`

Listed my code here

```
...
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(aMiddleware)
app.use("/api/foo", bar)

app.use(express.static('client/build'));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    const path = require('path');
    app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client', 'build', 'index.html'))
    })
}
```

**Questions**
Code is functioning, but I don't know how to replace the title/tag in the index.html

1. How do I update/replace index for environment that is not prod?
2. Fo prod environment, I use `path.resolve(__dirname, '../client', 'build', 'index.html')`, then where is index.html for dev environment? I see there is an index.html in `public` folder, is it the one that got rendered for dev environment?
3. I tried to add this code before `app.use(express.static(...))`

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) => {
    // maybe replace string in the index.html (though I don't know where is it
    // then res.send(...)?
})
```

but this never got triggered. Why?

Stuck on this for a while, tried many things, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-helmet for this... Or switch to Nextjs which is server side.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet